# Backup of MySQL database manually

Tags: server, filesystem, mysql

In the datadir of mysql are the folders named like the database. If I want to install this database on an other server manually, could I copy this folder on a e.g. USB stick and put it on the datadir of the other mysql server?
Theoretically is it possible, or?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in theory this is possible, as long as you make sure that neither service is running at the time of the copy/paste, and the new server is the same version as the old one. However, as you are well aware, it is not the recommended way.

Comment: If I stop the mysql service and then I copy this folder, it will be ok?

Comment: Yes, and stop the other mysql server before you paste the data.

Comment: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Fabby, you must be my biggest fan here.

Comment: Nah! You just showed up in the low quality queue...  >:)